# Can not catch runtime exception thrown by EntityManager.persist

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, exception, ejb

I have a stateless session bean called DatabaseService, here is code:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("handle runtime exception here: " + e.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

But the code in catch block never get executed, why is that?

If i modify code like this then catch block will works:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    try {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("handle runtime exception here: " + e.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Errm, and where is the Exception? How do you know there is one? Thrown at commit() perhaps? and where is commit() ? Put "flush()" within the try-catch and see what happens.

Comment: ah actually this persist method throw MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException since I tried to insert duplicate email address, but it's wrapped inside EJBTransactionRollbackException. I tried to catch it inside ejb method not in caller. Why do we need flush?

Comment: You need flush() because "persist" doesn't flush things to the datastore by default, as per the JPA spec

Comment: This is container-managed stateless session bean and it uses container-managed transaction JTA so it's not recommended to explicitly invoke commit

Comment: I tried with flush() but still catch block does not run, if i explicitly throw new runtime exception in try block and comment persist method then catch block will get invoked, strange

Comment: You've just said "persist" throws an Exception (MySQL type), so it will be caught ... if it is thrown and is an Exception (as opposed to an Error - use Throwable for that). Now you say it doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Ah you got me wrong! I mean for runtime exception that might occur in persist method (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) then catch block doesn't print "handle runtime exception here:" but If i remove method persist and throw new Runtime exception myself there in try block then catch block will print "handle runtime exception here:", is that clear

Comment: If the thrown exception implements Exception and is thrown from within that block then it will be caught. So post that exception and stack trace as part of your question and then people can offer their insights ... on where it is thrown from and why it is caught or not.

Comment: Nevermind I've found an explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246608/exception-not-cuaght-with-entity-manager, thanks for your care