# try to catch persist exception

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

simple problem. Here is the code :

```
public void insertDefacer(Defacer defacer) {
    try {
        em.persist(defacer);
    } catch (PersistenceException | DatabaseException e) {
        defacer = em.find(Defacer.class, defacer.getIdentity());
        defacer.setStats(defacer.getStats() + 1);
        em.merge(defacer);
    }
}
```

when ***defacer*** already exists in database (mysql), the `persist` operation throws an Exception (`PersistenceException` and/or `DatabaseException`). It seems normal. So I want to catch these exceptions and threat them. But after logging these exceptions, my program ends abruptly (without finish the method).

***Why ?***

Detail (It could be important or not) : ***em*** is an ***EntityManager*** get through ***@PersistenceContext***

Comment: where are you invoking the finish method from ?

Comment: I want that my catch run. But it is not the case.

Comment: I suspect that another `Exception` is happening inside your `catch` block.  Normally, your program should continue running, so there is likely something going on with your `EntityManager` to prevent this.

Comment: `But after logging these exceptions...` where have you logged these exceptions in your code?

Comment: Do you mean without invoking the `catch` block? Since you have only one line in your `try` block, it is no surprise that the method ends when there is an exception (as long as the exception is caught)

Comment: What do you mean with "without finishing the method"? I'm quite sure it can't just "end". Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the first line after the catch to see what happens?

Comment: Oh ok, the catch it's not executed, agree with @TimBiegeleisen.

Comment: @CodeNewbie, when I call the insertDefacer method in a parent object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246608/exception-not-cuaght-with-entity-manager

Comment: @Aucxence: How does the calling object get the exception object `e`? The logging must happen in your catch, not in the calling method.

Comment: Tim Biegelseinen, before theses exceptions I have **TransactionRollbackException**.

Comment: It seems that there is entitymanager problem. At some case commit is failed and so the rollback

Comment: wait 2 mins, guys, I test the solution of @TimBiegeleisen. It seems to be good.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative. Just see the code :

```
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void insertDefacer(Defacer defacer) {

   Defacer df = em.find(Defacer.class, defacer.getIdentity());
   if(df == null) {
      em.persist(defacer);
      System.out.println("Save");
   } else {
      em.merge(defacer);
      System.out.println("Update");
   }
```

}

As I said It's a ***palliative solution***. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this way to get EntityManager?

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
return em;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
this.em = em;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why do you think that **in getting EntityManager**, things will be different ? I need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using your `EntityManager` inside the `catch` clause as it may be in a corrupted state.  Exceptions in JPA are *not* recoverable, so you should assume that your transaction cannot and will not be completed if an Exception happens.

```
public void insertDefacer(Defacer defacer) {
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(defacer);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if(tx != null && tx.isActive()) tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if ***persist works***, your code will execute ***merge***. I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that that PersistenceExcetion belong to hibernate package.